# Unicode problem in konsole

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 13.04, konsole, utf-8

I have a problem with text encoding in konsole (I also tried xterm, things are the same) (Kubuntu 13.04, KDE). Here is the sample output:

```
oleg@PrizoffN:~$ gg
gg: \u043a\u043e\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0430
```

(Here `gg` is just random characters, so the answer should be `command not supported` or something like this)

```
oleg@PrizoffN:~$ sudo apt-get install krusader
[sudo] password for oleg: 
?????? ??????? ???????... ??????
?????????? ?????? ????????????       
?????? ?????????? ? ?????????... ??????
??? ??????????? ????? ????? ?????? krusader.
????????? 0, ??????????? 0 ????? ???????, ??? ???????? ???????? 0 ???????, ? 0 ??????? ?? ?????????.

oleg@PrizoffN:~$ uname -a
Linux PrizoffN 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Not sure why it is so... What can be done here?

In the same time, all is working well in pure console mode (If I press CTRL+ALT+F1)

**Update**: here is useful data:

```
oleg@PrizoffN:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1
LANGUAGE=en_US:ru:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_TIME="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_PAPER="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_NAME="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_ALL=
```

**Update 2**:

I was able to restore locale to its normal state by executing

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

But this was only temporary result. On konsole restarting locale is set back to its `ISO-8859-1` value. How can I store this permanently?

I also found this file:

```
oleg@PrizoffN:~$ cat .kde/env/setlocale.sh 
export LANG=en_US.utf8
export LANGUAGE=en_US:ru:en
```

where LANG was originally set to `ISO-8859-1`. I changed it to utf8 without any effect.

**UPDATE 3**:

After rebooting, locale returned to its normal state. So, no more problems.

Comment: on ubuntu 12.x or 13.04 ? what did you to facing local problem did you change system fonts ?

Comment: 13.04; What did I do before facing problem... Can't say for sure... Definitely it were not any new fonts, just played with locales.. it seems while installing packages with apt-get they report warning about absence LC_ALL value... Can't say for sure now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using a fresh installation of Kubuntu 13.04.

After installing the Russian locale and rebooting, I had the same problem. It was indeed due to the mismatch of the locale name in `.kde/env/setlocale.sh`.

So repeating the workaround:

```
LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1 =>>>
export LANG=en_US.utf8
```

and then rebooting fixed the problem totally!

Funny enough I've understood that there is a problem in the first place not in the `konsole` (this symptom is well present), but while browsing the data with Dolphin and seeing that all Russian-encoded files were abracadabra-named.